# Replace and remove duplicates string elements from one column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   id    room   area            room_vector
0   1   A-102  world        01 , 02, 03, 04
1   2     NaN     24                A; B; C
2   3    B309    NaN         s01, s02 , s02
3   4   C·102     25  E2702-2703,E2702-2703
4   5  E_1089  hello               03,05,06
5   6      27    NaN  05-08,09,10-12, 05-08
6   7      27    NaN                    NaN
```

I need to manipulate `room_vector` column with the following logic:
(1) remove `white spaces` and replace `;` with `,`;
(2) replace duplicates and keep one seperated by `,`.

For the first one, I've tried:

```
df['room_vector'] = df['room_vector'].str.replace([' ', ';'], '')
```

Out:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How could I get the expected result as follows:

```
   id    room   area            room_vector
0   1   A-102  world            01,02,03,04
1   2     NaN     24                  A,B,C
2   3    B309    NaN                s01,s02
3   4   C·102     25             E2702-2703
4   5  E_1089  hello               03,05,06
5   6      27    NaN         05-08,09,10-12
6   7      27    NaN                    NaN
```

Many thanks.

Comment: There are spaces only before/after  `,` and `;`  ?

Comment: Not sure, it could be in any positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is remove whitespaces, then split by `,` or `;` in  [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then remove duplicates with original order by create dictionary from keys and extracted `keys` but only for lists else is returned original:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()) if isinstance(x, list) else x
df['room_vector'] = df['room_vector'].str.replace(' ', '').str.split('[,;]').apply(f)
print(df)
   id    room   area     room_vector
0   1   A-102  world     01,02,03,04
1   2     NaN     24           A,B,C
2   3    B309    NaN         s01,s02
3   4   C·102     25      E2702-2703
4   5  E_1089  hello        03,05,06
5   6      27    NaN  05-08,09,10-12
6   7      27    NaN             NaN
```